# Import all Sheets in a Excel in different dataframes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a Excel-File with many sheets. I want to save each sheet in a dataframe. So for example:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('Test.XLS', sheet_name = 'sheet1', skiprows = 3)[:-1]
df2 = pd.read_excel('Test.XLS', sheet_name = 'sheet2', skiprows = 3)[:-1]
...
and so on...
```

But I dont want to do it manually instead I would like to do it in a loop or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can save the dataframes in a list and loop over the number of sheets. For example, if you have 10 sheets

```
df_list=[]

for i in range(1,11):
    df_list.append(pd.read_excel('Test.XLS', sheet_name = 'sheet'+str(i), skiprows = 3)[:-1])
```

In the case that the number of sheets is not known you can use a try-except

```
df_list=[]
i = 1
while True:
    try:
        df_list.append(pd.read_excel('Test.XLS', sheet_name = 'sheet'+str(i), skiprows = 3)[:-1])
        i+=1
    except:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to be flexible...so can I check how many sheets I have and then change the range based on the number of sheets ?

Answer (score 0):

This will read all sheets and put them in a dictionary (workbook) where the key is the sheet name and the value is the dataframe.

```
workbook = pd.read_excel('Test.XLS', sheet_name = None, skiprows = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

RTFM!

Doc for [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) says:

> sheet_name : str, int, list, or None, default 0
> ...
>           None: All sheets.

You can just do:

```
dfx = pd.read_excel('Test.XLS', sheet_name = None, skiprows = 3)
```

and you will a dictionary of all the sheets indexed with the sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your requirement.

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('read_sheets.xlsx')
sheets = xls.sheet_names # get the sheets from the excel file
sheet_names = list(sheets)#store the sheets names into list
for i in range(len(sheet_names)):
    globals()['df_'+sheet_names[i]] = pd.read_excel('read_sheets.xlsx', sheet_name = sheets[i])
```

df_Sheet1 is first dataframe

df_Sheet2 is second dataframe

df_Sheet3 is third dataframe etc..